# WordPress security

Tags: database, security

I created a website for my customer via wordpress and I uploaded it in their server ..we assume the user have the access in the whole server ..is it possible to protect this website from being used in other server by protect editing  admin password in database or adding a script that required my permission.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that sentence means. Would you try rephrasing it?

Comment: Sorry Im So Bad At Explaining  ...as you know every one who have some knowledge in wordpress can easily reset the password of wordpress admin via database and access to the back-end ..also this website created and uploaded in the server of our customer so they can easily hire someone with wordpress knowledge to change admin password via database ..that's why im wandering if it is possible to protect my admin password @s_ha_dum

Comment: You want to prevent the owner of the site from changing **your** admin password? That sounds like you are creating a backdoor to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and what you want is DRM and not security. The base of any measure of security is that only you have "root" level access to the server as the root user will be able in the end to overcome any DRM measure you try to implement.
If a contract will not stop him from violating your rights (assuming you have them at all), nothing will stop him.

If you want to restrict your user in such a away as you imply, you should not give him root/ftp access to the server.